# Is possible to do nested conditions for a list by comprehension?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'm challenging myself to turn something like this

```
if a and b and c:
  do_something(x) ## some function
elif a and b and c and d
  do_something(x[:-1]) ## the same function but slightly different
```

to something like this

```
cosa = [do_something(x) for x in X if a and b and c
        or
        do_something(x[:-1]) for x in X if a and b and c and d]
```

Is it possible in Python? I've already been told to use a for loop, but I'm intrigued if there's a way to handle this, given that the function `do_something`'s behaviour only varies by a bit.

---

A more specific description of what I want to do:

```
                history[chat_name] = [chats.message('chat_type',
                                                line.split(',',4)[3],
                                                line.split(',',4)[1],
                                                line.split(',',4)[2],
                                                line.split(',',4)[4][:-1]) 
                                      for line 
                                      in file 
                                      if line.split(',',4)[0] == chat_type 
                                      and line.split(',',4)[2] == chat_name]
```

I'm writing a code that's supposed to emulate a chat app. The variable `chat_type` indicates if it is a group chat ('grupo') or if it is an individual chat ('regular'). Since, when speaking of a chat group, it doesn't matter who sends the message as long as they are on the group, this code is sufficient and gets the work done.

However, when it comes to an individual chat, the above makes the code include all messages written by anyone to a given recipient. I'd like to add the condition that, if, and only if, the chat_type is set to 'regular', then the code has to make sure the sender is the current user.

I fixed as follows:

```
            if chat_type == 'grupo':
                history[chat_name] = [chats.message('chat_type',
                                                line.split(',',4)[3],
                                                line.split(',',4)[1],
                                                line.split(',',4)[2],
                                                line.split(',',4)[4][:-1]) 
                                      for line 
                                      in file 
                                      if line.split(',',4)[0] == chat_type 
                                      and line.split(',',4)[2] == chat_name]
            elif chat_type == 'regular':
                history[chat_name] = [chats.message('chat_type',
                                                line.split(',',4)[3],
                                                line.split(',',4)[1],
                                                line.split(',',4)[2],
                                                line.split(',',4)[4][:-1]) 
                                      for line 
                                      in file 
                                      if line.split(',',4)[0] == chat_type 
                                      and line.split(',',4)[2] == chat_name
                                      and line.split(',',4)[1] == self.username] ##this is the extra condition
```

I hope this helps in answering my question.

Comment: This is a case study in exactly why you shouldn't try to cram everything into a list comprehension. yes what you are trying to do is possible, use conditional expressions. But it is highly indadvisable

Comment: While it's just for illustrative purposes, it's worth noting in your example that `a and b and c and d` can't be true without `a and b and c` being true first, so your `elif` can't trigger

Answer (score 0):

this should be the right way to do what you need

```
cosa = [do_something(x) if a and b and c else do_something(x[:-1]) if a and b and c and d for x in X]
```